# Python. Tkinter. Curselection

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

В общем, есть графический интерфейс, в котором есть однострочное поле для ввода(***Entry***), многострочное(***Text***), список(***ListBox***) и кнопка(***Button***). Кнопка и однострочное поле надо для ввода чего-либо в многострочное поле, а список содержит название txt файлов.

Как сделать так, чтобы когда я выбирал файл из списка, то все, что в нем есть, выводилось в многострочное поле, а после того как нажимал на другой файл в листбоксе, то прошлый файл, который был выбран, сохранял все, что есть в многострочном поле и закрывался, ну и соответственно открывался следующий выбранный.

Пока, есть только функция по определению индекса и значения выбраного файла в списке:

```
def onselect(evt):
    w = evt.widget
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    value = w.get(index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну примерно так можно реализовать
P.s можно конечно создать отдельный класс `LisBox` "для красоты", но слишком запористо :D

```
import tkinter as tk
import os


class Main(tk.Tk):
    open_close = True

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.entry = tk.Entry()
        self.text = tk.Text()
        self.list_box = tk.Listbox()
        self.list_box.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.file_operation)
        for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
            _, j = os.path.splitext(i)
            if j == ".txt":
                self.list_box.insert(tk.END, i)
        but = tk.Button(text="Добавить", command=self.add_item)
        self.entry.pack()
        but.pack()
        self.text.pack()
        self.list_box.pack()

    def file_operation(self, e):
        if self.open_close:
            self.file_name = self.list_box.get(e.widget.curselection())
            with open(self.file_name, encoding="utf-8") as file:
                self.text.delete("1.0", tk.END)
                self.text.insert(tk.END, file.read())
                self.open_close = False
        else:
            with open(self.file_name, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                file.write(self.text.get("1.0", tk.END))
            self.open_close = True
            self.file_operation(e)

    def add_item(self):
        self.text.insert(tk.END, self.entry.get() + "\n")
        self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().mainloop()
```